# Image scale without loose quality

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I tried to scale an image from an API but I have a problem when I try to adapt this in my tableview.
I want to scale image with the correct width of the screen for display and keep the ratio image. For each cells in my table View, I have this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = portfolioTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OnePhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OnePhotoCell
    cell.onePhotoImageView.image = arrayPhotos[indexPath.row].imagePhoto
}
```

The cell contains imageView with content mode aspect fill. And to keep the ratio I do this too :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
let image = self.arrayPhotos[indexPath.row].imagePhoto
return image.size.height
}
```

And for scale my image I use this function :

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let oldWidth = Float(image.size.width)
        let scaleFactor = Float(self.view.frame.width) / oldWidth
        let newHeight = Float(image.size.height) * scaleFactor
        let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor
        let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(newWidth), height: CGFloat(newHeight))
        let newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0,0, CGFloat(newWidth), CGFloat(newHeight)))
        let imageRef = image.CGImage

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, .High)
        let flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, CGFloat(newHeight))

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical)
        CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef)

        let newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)! as CGImage
        let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: newImageRef)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
```

The problem with this function is the ratio is keeping but I lose quality on my image. 
Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let image = self.arrayPhotos[indexPath.row].imagePhoto
    return image.size.height / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I try this but it does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

try scaleFactor should be

```
let scaleFactor = Float(self.view.frame.width * UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale) / oldWidth
```

and

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1.0)
```